# Terminator Bash - How to create shortcut to folders

Tags: command-line, bash, terminator

I am using Terminator as my bash cli. Is there a way to create shortcut commands to relevant folders? e.g. We have the default `cd ~` which takes us to Home folder.

How can I create my own custom shortcuts to relevant folders? Reason for asking is that I would like to have shortcuts to various projects within my `/var/www/*` folders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command from the bash

`alias yourAlias='cd /var/www/html'`

Here is `/var/www/html` is the location you want. It could be anything else.

Then you have only to type

`yourAlias`

from your terminal to go to the desired location what you have already defined.

If you want to make your aliases permanent, add them to the `.bash_aliases` file in your home directory (create it if necessary), the changes apply for every terminal you open after changing the file.

Comment: This is as close as you can get IMO without creating a function in `BASH` that would take an argument.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean exactly? What does IMO mean?
This is how I am doing it on my online VPS.

Comment: @dessert would you please clarify

Comment: @Mark A function does not necessarily have to take an argument, `yourAlias(){ cd /var/www/html;}` gives the exact same result as the alias. Just that it's unnecessary here. :)

Comment: @dessert Yes, thanks, I'm quite aware functions do not require arguments but the OP indicated `cd ~` such that the argument passed was the Tilda. To reproduce the ability to have arguments that would vary, a function would be necessary, not an alias. @Peshmerge IMO=In My Opinion

Comment: @Mark OK, but you can very well do `alias a=cd` and then `a ~`. In fact that's how some aliases are predefined in your `~/.bashrc` file, e.g. `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` which enables colored output of `grep` by default – calling it as `\grep` disables the alias for this time.